# Audio does not play when I click on the div box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have div with class testspeech, and when I click on this box, an audio from my uploads folder starts playing.
How can I pause the audio if I click again on the same div?
The end result is having the audio play and pause like a normal play/pause button.

```
var obj = document.createElement("audio");
var counts = 0;
console.log(counts);
document.body.appendChild(obj);
obj.src = ".../wp-content/uploads/audios/Kalimba.mp3";
obj.load();
obj.volume = 0.3;
obj.preLoad = true;
obj.controls = true;
//obj.autoplay = true;

$(".testspeech").click(function() {
    if(counts == 0){
        console.log(counts);
        obj.play();      
    }
    else{
        obj.pause();
        counts = 0;   
        console.log(counts);
    }
});
```

I used css to hide the button from the screen:

```
audio{
    display: none;
}
```

At the moment the audio plays when I click in it, but it never stops.

Comment: You never set `counts` to a truthy value...

Answer (score 1):

Check audio "paused" property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="testspeech">
play/pause
</button><br/>
<script>
var obj = document.createElement("audio");
document.body.appendChild(obj);
obj.src = ".../wp-staging/07/wp-content/uploads/audios/Kalimba.mp3";
obj.load();
obj.volume = 0.3;
obj.preLoad = true;
obj.controls = true;

$(".testspeech").click(function() {
   obj.paused?obj.play():obj.pause()
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After posting this question the website got hacked. Do you mind perhaps changing the url that is in your html?